# .net Core - compatibility of docker images

Tags: docker, .net-core

According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/, the newest version of .NET core should be backward compatible with the previous versions.

However, building a docker image with 2.2sdk won't run on a container with runtime 3.0... Am I missing something or is it the normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention of that in the linked article?

What you are experiencing is normal behavior. Major versions are not backwards compatible (for runtimes).

In your case running a `.net core 2.2` app will not work on an image with a `.net core 3.0` runtime.

You can read more about [version selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward) where the following is mentioned:

> The host chooses the latest patch version installed on the machine. For example, if you specified `netcoreapp2.0` in your project file, and `2.0.4` is the latest .NET runtime installed, the `2.0.4` runtime is used.
>
> If no acceptable `2.0.*` version is found, a new `2.*` version is used. For example, if you specified `netcoreapp2.0` and only `2.1.0` is installed, the application runs using the `2.1.0` runtime. This behavior is referred to as "minor version roll-forward." Lower versions also won't be considered. When no acceptable runtime is installed, the application won't run.
>
> A few usage examples demonstrate the behavior, if you target 2.0:
>
> - 2.0 is specified. 2.0.5 is the highest patch version installed. 2.0.5 is used.
> - 2.0 is specified. No 2.0.* versions are installed. 1.1.1 is the highest runtime installed. An error message is displayed.
> - 2.0 is specified. No 2.0.* versions are installed. 2.2.2 is the highest 2.x runtime version installed. 2.2.2 is used.
> - **2.0 is specified. No 2.x versions are installed. 3.0.0 is installed. An error message is displayed.**

They also mention roughly adhering to semantic versioning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/#semantic-versioning):

> `MAJOR` is incremented when:
>
> - Significant changes occur to the product, or a new product direction.
> - Breaking changes were taken. There's a high bar to accepting breaking changes.
> - **An old version is no longer supported.**
> - A newer `MAJOR` version of an existing dependency is adopted.